# I can't upload the node_modules folder to github

Tags: github, large-files, git-lfs

The folder is over 100 MB and you must use Git LFS. However, how do I upload folders? It's the first time I'm using it, someone help me please

Comment: Your actual problem is that you shouldn't commit your node_modules into the repo. It should be generated from your package.json.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand you well.
I'm using Electron, I'm still learning. Should I not upload the node_modules folder on github?

Comment: @GabrielEdu You shouldn't. The node_modules can be recreated just using the entries on _packages.json_ file. You just need to remove this directory from git using `git rm --cached node_modules` and then add it to the gitignore file.

Comment: I already did. I deleted the node_modules folder and remembered that just give "npm i", that it installs all dependencies. Thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github push declined due to large file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60602430/github-push-declined-due-to-large-file-size)